# Ubuntu-Mate Ethernet cable SSH

Tags: pi-3, ethernet, ubuntu

I am trying to connect my Raspberry Pi 3 to my laptop using Ethernet to avoid the use of a keyboard, mouse, and screen. I installed on my sd card Ubuntu Mate 16.04 and I configured it. I installed also Openssh server.

After that, I changed the local area network settings on my PC (Windows):

- Obtain an IP Address automatically
- Sharing Settings: Allow other networks to connect through this computer's... (to make internet connection available to my Rpi through my PC wifi)

However, this does not work. Then, I tried connecting my Rpi to a router, and I installed on my phone ConnectBot. I was able to connect to Rpi through the Router via ssh. The thing is that I am trying to achieve the connection without a router (only ethernet cable).

I used to do the above steps with my Raspberry Pi model B and Raspbian OS. I used to ping raspberry.mshome.net, get the IP, and connect using Putty. With Ubuntu Mate I am always getting "Connection Refused". I searched the internet and there are no clear documentation or steps to do this. Can you suggest any article or steps? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to have samba installed on your RPi for hostname resolution to work in Windows. Try running `sudo apt-get install samba` on your RPi and retry the same direct connection steps. Also double check the hostname your RPi has (by running the `hostname` command or checking `/etc/hostname`), it may be different in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Specify IP addresses for both your Pi and your PC and see if it's OK.

Obtaining IP address automatically only works when there's a DHCP server, which is your router in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If this is the case, can you please explain why it worked on my raspberry pi 2 (Raspbian) with the steps I described? Thanks Again!